# Batch File to Search for a String within Directory Names

Tags: loops, batch-file

My batch file terminates prematurely after I assign the first environmental variable (script output below). I've tried turning echo on, using errorlevels, sending the output to a text file, and checking syntax. I've spent several hours researching debugging batch scripts, but I have finally hit a brick wall.

Script's Goal: Search each directory name of the user's Program Files, looking for common antivirus programs. I realize that it would be easiest iterate through an array of antivirus names for this purpose, but I want to keep it simple for now.

```
@echo off
::variables
set AntiVirus1="Initial Value"

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 echo %ERRORLEVEL%
else echo "env. variable created successfully."

for /d %%f in (""%ProgramFiles%\*"") do (
{
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 echo %ERRORLEVEL%

   echo "%%f"
   if exist /i "*McAfee*" < %%f %AntiVirus1%="McAfee"
   ::find "Norton" < %%f
   ::find "Comodo" < %%f
   ::find "AVG" < %%f

}

echo %AntiVirus1%

@pause
```

Output of this script:

C:\Users\Matt\Desktop>set AntiVirus1="Initial Value" 
C:\Users\Matt\Desktop>

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE** Corrected script, now working but returning incorrect results:

```
::@echo off
::variables
set AntiVirus1="Initial Value"

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (echo %ERRORLEVEL%) ELSE echo "env. variable created successfully."

echo Checking Program Files...
for /d %%f in ("%ProgramFiles%\*") do (
   echo "%%f"
   if %%f=="*adobe*" set AntiVirus1="adobe"
)

echo %AntiVirus1% found

@pause
```

Comment: Please do not update questions like that. Not only you made your post inconsistent (you first paragraph refers to a premature termination that is no longer the issue with the script that follows!), but also devoided the first part of my answer. Presently I fixed that by adding the modified script below your original text. You might want to update the post further with explicit wording of your additional request, if you think that necessary.

Comment: Good call. I'll make sure to do this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `ELSE` must be on the same line with `IF` *or* on the same line with the closing parenthesis that pertains to `IF`. In you particular case you should change your first `IF...ELSE` command like this:

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%) ELSE ECHO "env. variable created successfully."
```

or like this:

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
  ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
) ELSE ECHO "env. variable created successfully."
```

(Capitalisation and indentation are perfectly optional.)

Other issues:

- Duplicated quotation marks in the `FOR` loop header:

  ```
  for /d %%f in (""%ProgramFiles%\*"") do (
  ```

  should be

  ```
  for /d %%f in ("%ProgramFiles%\*") do (
  ```
- Braces (`{`, `}`) around the loop body. They are not part of the loop syntax (in fact, they are not part of batch scripting syntax at all), so should be dropped.
- No closing parenthesis matching the opening one after `DO`. It should be added on a separate line after the loop body.
- Incorrect use of `::`-style comments in the loop body. They are not allowed inside bracketed blocks. Use `REM` instead.

---

**UPDATE**

In batch scripting, testing for a substring is done somewhat unusually. You'll need another environment variable and you'll also need to enable delayed expansion. The latter is not really connected with the comparison, but it is needed because the comparison is going to be performed within a bracketed block.

Here's your new script modified, with the changes highlighted:

```
::@echo off
::variables
set AntiVirus1="Initial Value"

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (echo %ERRORLEVEL%) ELSE echo "env. variable created successfully."

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Checking Program Files...
for /d %%f in ("%ProgramFiles%\*") do (
   echo "%%f"
   SET "folder=%%f"
   if /I NOT "!folder:adobe=!"=="!folder!" set AntiVirus1="adobe"
)

echo %AntiVirus1% found

@pause
```

Here's a bit of explanation.

The `!` syntax is a delayed expansion equivalent of `%` and is used with environment variables only, *not* with loop variables and *not* with command line parameters. Delayed expansion is needed because we are in a bracketed block. A bracketed block is parsed entirely before it starts executing, so all `%var%` expressions are expanded (evaluated) before the block starts and are not changed throughout the block's execution. That cannot suit us because we need to assign different values to a variable during the block's execution, and the values must be read within the block. Delayed expansion, as follows from the name, delays the expansion of a variable until the actual execution of every single command that references that variable. Because immediate expansion can still be used alongside delayed expansion, a different syntax is introduced, which is `!` around variable names, instead of `%`.

`!folder:adobe=!` means evaluate `folder` replacing every occurrence of `adobe` with an empty string. The result of this expression is then compared to the (unchanged) value of `folder`. If there's a match, then the replacement didn't occur, which means there was no `adobe` in the value of `folder` in the first place. In this case we should do nothing. But if there was *not* a match, i.e. if the modified value didn't match the unmodified one, then we should set the `AntiVirus1` variable. This is why there's `NOT` in front of the comparison.

The `/I` option simply means case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the bad syntax. I've cleaned it up, but my AntiVirus1 var is always "Initial Value" when the script ends. Is there something I need to change with the conditional statement? I'm using "adobe" instead of "mcafee", since that's a folder I can test with. My new code is in the original post.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, the `!folder:adobe=!` statement both finds any instance of the word adobe **and** replaces it in the local variable `folder`? %AntiVirus1% will then be changed if a substring in the folder name matches whatever is in the `folder` variable.
I've just got a couple small questions about the syntax. I thought the colon was a symbol to create labels? Also, how does DOS know that the equals sign at the end of `!folder:adobe=!` is not part of the string to search (in this case, "adobe") if it's not separated by a space?

Comment: @KongMD: Yes, the expression both searches for a substring and replaces it, but *the variable is **not** affected.* The expression follows this template: `%var:string1=string2%`. `%`, `:`, `=` are all part of the syntax. `%`s are replaced with `!`s because we need to use delayed expansion. `:` separates the variable name from the part that follows which is the substring to find. `=` separates the substring from the following part, which the string to replace the substring we are looking for, and in our particular case it's an empty string (there's nothing between `=` and the closing `!`).

Comment: So the effect is, all occurrences of `adobe` are simply removed (if found). You can find more extensive information on the topic by issuing `help set` or `set /?` at the command prompt. But you are welcome to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanations! I'll add the final script to my original post after I've polished up a few things :)